# VB6 or VBA - I have the image data (source) can I find out the image type and name from that?

Tags: image, vba, vb6

I only have the data of the image. How do I interogate this data to get type and its name?

Taking a shot in the dark that this is possible.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to examine the file structure and make a determination based on that.  I would start with: http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html

Comment: Thank you. Sory for the late response